# Clickable buttons outside safe area

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Is is possible to have buttons clickable outside safe area (btw how is it called? nonsafe area?)? I have buttons like in screenshot and highlight area where my app doesn't recognize touch (it's screenshot from simulator iPhone XR, there is notch but it's not visible in screenshot):
[image: iPhone XR screenshot]

I know that some systems buttons are clickable in that area but I don't know why mine isn't.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, buttons do not respond to touches outside of the safe area. And this is for a good reason. Areas outside of the safe area are reserved for iOS system user interface, like displaying the time, battery level, and your cellular signal strength.

Apple advises to account for safe area insets when laying out your UI elements.

Try running this project on a device like iPhone X or iPhone 11 to test it out: https://github.com/ChopinDavid/safearea